# Generate PDF docs with HTML2PDF using both P and L orientation in some pages

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

Is it possible to use both Portrait and Landscape orientation in the same pdf document (the same thing with Microsoft Office) with the library HTML2PDF. 
Thank you for your help !

Comment: I want to generate a PDF document containing both texts and very large table and this is why I need Landscape Orientation. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the HTM2PDF [html to pdf library](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk), but I think you're using a different one.

I work for HTM2PDF and can highly recommend it.